# Removing ports dynamically from " joint.shapes.devs.Model " JointJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, jointjs

I'm trying to remove ports dynamically from a cell in joitJS, so i have a element:

```
var em = new joint.shapes.devs.Model({
                    position: {x: ev.offsetX, y: ev.offsetY},
                    size: {width: 100, height: 40},
                    attrs: {
                        '.label': {text: bname, fill: 'white'},
                        rect: {fill: '#1ABC9C', stroke: "#000","stroke-width": 0},
                        '.inPorts circle': {
                            fill: '#16A085',
                            magnet: 'passive',
                            type: 'input',
                            'stroke-width': 0,
                            r: 8
                        },
                        '.outPorts circle': {fill: '#E74C3C', type: 'output',"stroke-width": 0, stroke: "#000",r: 8}
                    },
                    file: bname + ".txt",
                    input: "url",
                    name: bname,
                    inPorts: [''],
                    outPorts: [''],
                    output: "txt"
  });
```

I'm adding it dynamically, and the ports to, with this function:

```
function addInPort(name, opt){
    var portsArray = currCell.model.get('inPorts') || [];
    currCell.model.set('inPorts', portsArray.concat([name]), opt);
}
```

and this is the remove one:

```
function removeInPort(opt){
    var portsArray = currCell.model.get('inPorts') || [];
    portsArray.shift();
    console.log(portsArray);
    currCell.model.set('inPorts',portsArray, opt);
}
```

when I try removing a port from the ports Array, it does not render the ports, it deletes them from the array but it does not render them.

I've tried array.slice(), array.shift(), but they don't render, with  slice it does but it removes all the ports.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

See https://groups.google.com/g/jointjs/c/9oVtclUXDxU/m/I1iN0-LPAgAJ.

TL/DR:
Since you use the joint.shapes.devs, stick with the API it provides. Do not combine it with the Element Port API e.g. addPort, removePort.
`devs` shapes store the ports in `inPorts` and `outPorts` attributes; these ports are not updated when you attempt to change the ports with the Element Port API.
See https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.1/joint.html#shapes.devs